# What is the purpose of 192.168.1.0?

Tags: networking, ip-address

AFAIK an IP address ending with `x.x.x.0` doesn't point to a specific host, but to the whole subnet.

However it's not clear to me what happens if I send a packet to e.g. `192.168.1.0`: could you please show me an example?

Comment: Are you looking at this from a host on the same subnet, for example 192.168.1.2? What is the subnet mask?

Comment: To answer ""what happens if I send a packet to e.g. 192.168.1.0?" you need to provide more details, specifically if you want more details than given in https://superuser.com/a/1806242/964771.

Comment: related: [All IP Addresses Are Equal? "dot-zero" Addresses Are Less Equal](https://labs.ripe.net/author/stephane_bortzmeyer/all-ip-addresses-are-equal-dot-zero-addresses-are-less-equal/). They're only special (identifying the subnet) in classfull routing.

Answer (score 15):

x.x.x.0 traditionally is a broadcast address. (Was later changed to x.x.x.255)

It will forward your request to all ipaddresses in the range 1/254, but only if the OS supports it. By default on OSX and Linux, this is enabled. for Windows you need to enable SetIPUseZeroBroadcast WMI to enable it.

The x.x.x.0 address is generally used for routing purposes, and some routers will respond and direct the traffic to itself.

I was taught in school to treat the x.x.x.0 address as the network cable. Even though it is a metaphor, it holds up.

Comment: This is technically wrong, since some `x.x.x.0` is for certain the network id only if the IP subnet is a `/24` (or smaller).

Comment: @TomYan Pedantic mode on: The ip-address ending in .0 is ALWAYS the network-id in a /24 subnet, but for both larger and smaller subnets not necessarily. E.g 192.168.1.0 is in the middle of 192.168.0.0/23 and at 1/4 of 192.168.0.0/22. Smaller subnets don't always start at the .0 boundary. The .0 is only the network-address for those networks that start at that address and smaller subnets may not even contain a .0 address at all. . E.g. 192.168.168.128 is the network address for 192.168.1.128/25.

Comment: @Tonny that's why I had parentheses for `or smaller`, implying "only when a given `.0` is relevant in a given subnet". (If it is not even within the block, then the question `what is the purpose` wouldn't even make sense. ;-))

Comment: An address ending in .0 is ALWAYS a network ID in a /24 or smaller subnet.  It may not be the network ID for any GIVEN subnet, but if you have an IP ending in .0 and the mask is /24 or smaller (/25,/26,/27,/28 etc) then it will be a network address.  If you go binary, you have ????????.????????.????????.000000000.  A network address is an address in which all the host bits are 0.  Thence, any mask of /24 -> 32 for an address ending in 0 will have all the host bits be zero.

Comment: And there's of course the case of /31s where the two possible addresses are actual host addresses and not broadcast (on hosts which support that, usually routers, fo point-to-point links).

Comment: I understand this is an obsolete use of the .0 address. These days it does nothing special, but is still avoided, for compatibility with really old systems.

Comment: After 25 years in IT, I shouldn't be surprised that this inaccurate and unhelpful answer has a positive score, but I am.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Nothing stops you from posting an answer of your own. Do so, and tell us what the real answer is according to what you've learned.

Answer (score 11):

The use of "0" and "1" in a IP addresses was defined in [RFC923](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc923)
and carried over in successive RFCs:

```
Special Addresses:

  In certain contexts, it is useful to have fixed addresses with
  functional significance rather than as identifiers of specific
  hosts.  When such usage is called for, the address zero is to be
  interpreted as meaning "this", as in "this network".  The address
  of all ones are to be interpreted as meaning "all", as in "all
  hosts".  For example, the address 128.9.255.255 could be
  interpreted as meaning all hosts on the network 128.9.  Or, the
  address 0.0.0.37 could be interpreted as meaning host 37 on this
  network.
```

The "ending-0" notation is also sometimes used for routing purposes,
to indicate the source and destination sub-networks as a whole.

A complete treaty of this subject is found in Wikipedia
[Internet Protocol version 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol_version_4)
section "First and last subnet addresses":

> The first address in a subnet is used to identify the subnet itself.
> In this address all host bits are 0. To avoid ambiguity in
> representation, this address is reserved. The last address has all
> host bits set to 1. It is used as a local broadcast address for
> sending messages to all devices on the subnet simultaneously. For
> networks of size /24 or larger, the broadcast address always ends in
> 255.
>
> In the past, conflict between network addresses and broadcast
> addresses arose because some software used non-standard broadcast
> addresses with zeros instead of ones.

This Wikipedia article section also contains examples to illustrate
the rules.

Answer (score 0):

### Some History

[RFC 1122: Requirements for Internet Hosts -- Communication Layers](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1122):

> [3.3.6  Broadcasts](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1122#page-66)
>
> Section 3.2.1.3 defined the four standard IP broadcast address forms:
>
> Limited Broadcast: {-1, -1}
>
> Directed Broadcast: {<Network-number>,-1}
>
> Subnet Directed Broadcast: {<Network-number>,<Subnet-number>,-1}
>
> All-Subnets Directed Broadcast: {<Network-number>,-1,-1}
>
> A host MUST recognize any of these forms in the destination address of
> an incoming datagram.

Note that while there are probably obsolete (predating classless routing) versions of broadcast (2 are left: limited broadcast: 255.255.255.255 and subnet directed broadcast just called directed broadcast today, eg: 192.168.1.255 in the network 192.168.1.0/24) , there is (yet) no .0 definition. But below:

> There is a class of **hosts*** that use **non-standard broadcast** address
> forms, **substituting 0 for -1**.  All hosts **SHOULD**  [...]
>
> ---
>
> ***4.2BSD Unix** and its derivatives, but not 4.3BSD.
>
> [...] recognize and accept any of these **non-standard broadcast
> addresses** as the destination address of an incoming datagram.
>
> A host MAY optionally have a configuration option to choose the  0 or
> the -1 form of broadcast address, for each physical  interface, but
> this option SHOULD default to the standard (-1)  form.

So because of 4.2BSD historical non-standard behavior and for the sake of compatibility with it, .0 has also been considered a broadcast for more than 30 years.

---

### What happens if I send a packet to e.g. 192.168.1.0 (in the LAN 192.168.1.0/24)?

So in the LAN 192.168.1.0/24, most systems until today will consider 192.168.1.0 as a broadcast, in addition to 192.168.1.255 and/or possibly any other address configured as broadcast address: there's no real use of an additional broadcast address, so that's one address wasted that can't be used by an host. in a /24 that's 1/256 wasted: quite negligible. In a /29 (with 8 addresses) as can be rented at an host provider, that's 1/8 or ~ 12.5% of the address space wasted: not negligible anymore.

Here are two Linux examples.

On Linux kernel 5.10:

```shell
# ip addr add 192.168.1.1/24 broadcast 192.168.1.255 dev eth0
# ping 192.168.1.0
Do you want to ping broadcast? Then -b. If not, check your local firewall rules.
# nc -n -v 192.168.1.255 9
nc: connect to 192.168.1.255 port 9 (tcp) failed: Network is unreachable
# nc -n -v 192.168.1.0 9
nc: connect to 192.168.1.0 port 9 (tcp) failed: Network is unreachable
# ip route get 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.0 dev eth0 src 192.168.1.1 uid 0 
    cache <local,brd>
```

ICMP (or UDP) requires to specify that it's a broadcast to be permitted to emit, and the common Linux variant of `ping` doesn't do it itself automatically (it requires `-b`). TCP fails because it can't be used with broadcast: .0 is considered just as .-1: a broadcast.

Probably any Windows, Unix, (incl. MacOS, BSD) or router brand (Cisco, ...) will behave likewise.

But on Linux >= 5.14:

```shell
# ip addr add 192.168.1.2/24 broadcast 192.168.1.255 dev eth0
# ping -t 4 -c 1 192.168.1.0
PING 192.168.1.0 (192.168.1.0) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.2 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 192.168.1.0 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
# time nc -n -v 192.168.1.0 9
nc: connect to 192.168.1.0 port 9 (tcp) failed: No route to host

real    0m3,086s
user    0m0,000s
sys 0m0,003s
# ip route get 192.168.1.0
192.168.1.0 dev eth0 src 192.168.1.2 uid 0 
    cache 
# ip neigh show 192.168.1.0
192.168.1.0 dev enp2s0 FAILED
```

Here 192.168.1.0 is now considered a normal (unicast) address. It triggers an ARP request (which fails as usual when there's no answer after 3s).

Linux' change was made in this commit (available in kernel 5.14+):

> [ip: Treat IPv4 segment's lowest address as unicast](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/net/ipv4?id=94c821c74bf5fe0c25e09df5334a16f98608db90)
>
> Treat **only the highest, not the lowest**, IPv4 address within a local
> subnet **as a broadcast address**.

So depending on the OS and its version, the behavior might differ: either it's following the *SHOULD* of the RFC to be compatible with 4.2BSD from 1980s and considers it's a broadcast, or it's taking exception of this *SHOULD* (which is not a *MUST* but only a *SHOULD* after all) and considers it's a normal unicast address.

Even with such change, as nothing should use the .0 address, there's no harm done.

But if all systems in the LAN consider .0 as an unicast address (eg: if all of them are running Linux >= 5.14), including the router, then the .0 address becomes available, for example for an additional node. Else any node considering it as a broadcast and seeing an ARP request from this .0 address will ignore it since it considers it as invalid (a broadcast address cannot be a source address, only a destination): no connectivity between them.

For very small networks such as /29 that means there's less waste: one can now use 7 of the 8 addresses for nodes in this LAN, or 6 + 1 when accounting for the router, instead of 6 or 5+1, as long as all nodes (including router) are not considering .0 as a broadcast anymore.

This benefit can possibly counterbalance some people's <s>scream for bloody murder</s> reluctance against such change.

Comment: I think the text of the RFC is somewhat misleading – as far as I know, BSD began to use all-zeros when there was no standard for a broadcast address whatsoever, so either choice was as reasonable as the other; it's the RFC that *made* all-zeros explicitly non-standard by codifying all-ones.

Comment: @u1686_grawity perhaps, but we usually (but not always) follow RFC. As .-1 is the (RFC-official as well as de facto) history winner, having two broadcasts is still useless and a waste, and it appears some people want this unfortunate state to stop (eg: those that made the change in Linux 5.14+) for some practical reasons. And I did answer OP to tell what happens when one tries to reach 192.168.1.0: it depends.